# Huawei JNI libart segfault

Tags: python, android, c++, java-native-interface, huawei-mobile-services

I have written an android app that executes python 3.8 scripts through JNI. This app works well on samsung, wiko and emulator devices but it randomly crashes on a Huawei P30 device with this backtrace:

```
* thread #37, name = 'Thread-3', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
  * frame #0: 0x00000072845feeec libart.so`art_sigsegv_fault
    frame #1: 0x00000072845ff3f4 libart.so`art::FaultManager::HandleFault(int, siginfo*, void*) + 356
    frame #2: 0x0000006127553da8 app_process64`___lldb_unnamed_symbol24$$app_process64 + 592
    frame #3: 0x000000730b946638 [vdso]
    frame #4: 0x000000720eebbba8
```

Going through the python script I put print traces all around but it never crashes at the same point in the script. I'm wondering what I could do to further investigate this crash (and if there is anything that would prevent them). As you can see the backtrace is not giving much information.
I found a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46888420/stdexception-sigsegv-on-huawei-jni) on c++ exceptions but the solution did not work for me.

Comment: Can you pls recreate an application and extract the code for executing the Python script file separately (not involving any business code of your application).Then package the code of the new application and send it to hmscore@huawei.com for us to check?(You can compress the code into a .zip file and change the file name extension to .apk.)